# find specific float number in string?

Tags: php, regex

i would like to find specific float number from string using regex .
string

```
202-715-1278 2 0.01% 0.30 0.00% $0.00 0.00%
```

the only number i need to find this one 0.30 .
i tried a lot of patterns but all of them return the whole float numbers within the string and some of them not working at it all

```
[-+]?([0-9]*\,)?[0-9]+
\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

also i tried

```
floatval()
```

but it doesn't work neither

Comment: What's the pattern? Are you trying to get always the 4th number? only the second that is a floating number?

Comment: im trying to get this one 0.30 which don't have % or $

Comment: This is still not clear. The first number which hasn't a % or $ is 2. If you want always 0.30, just do $var = 0.30

Comment: Explode the string on a `" "` then use a regex for the elements?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa the first number 2 is integer not float and the 0.30 is not a fixed number

Comment: It sounds like you want to know if 0.30 is in the string, not the value of any particular number in the string.  If that's the case it's a much simpler problem.

Comment: @SurrealDreams Read the comment posted 2 minutes before yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<!\$)\b[-+]?\d+\.\d+\b(?!%)
```

It matches a number with a decimal point in it, but not preceded by `$` or followed by `%`.

See [RegExr](http://regexr.com?35d4k)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a number surrounded by spaces (if it is what you are looking for) with:

```
(?:^|\s)\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s|$)
```

explanation:

```
(?:^|\s)   # the begining of the string or a white character
\K         # reset all that is matched before
\d+        # digit one or more times
(?:\.\d+)? # optional dot and digits
(?=\s|$)   # followed by a white character or the end of the string
```

Comment: @Dr.Neo: Normal, rubular is for ruby not for php. And ruby doesn't support the `\K` feature. Use http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the string format is static (eg. it doesn't change), then why use a regex to find it?

The string component you're looking for can easily be located by exploding the string based on spaces and with little effort:

```
$string = "202-715-1278 2 0.01% 0.30 0.00% $0.00 0.00%";
$parts = explode(' ', $string);
echo $parts[3]; // 0.30
```

In addition, if you use a regex, any developer who consequently comes across your code will have to spend time understanding it - unless you document it well!